# How to get number of correct responses /answers for quizzes questions in Moodle?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am completely new to Moodle. I have been wondering for quiz questions analysis purpose.

How can I get the no. of correct responses or incorrect responses and the user_id for the person responsible for those answers. Is there any table which already stores that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task and I solved it finally. I found the questions is graded in table called mdl_question_attempt_steps I joined it with the moodle question and grouped by the question and counted the right and wrong answers.

After more than 8 hours of searching and reading the very complex moodle code this is the query.

```
SELECT questionid, 
COUNT( CASE WHEN state =  "gradedright" THEN 1  END ) AS rightanswer,
COUNT( CASE WHEN state =  "gradedwrong" THEN 1  END ) AS wronganswer
FROM  `mdl_question_attempt_steps` 
JOIN mdl_question_attempts ON (  `questionattemptid` = mdl_question_attempts.id ) 
JOIN mdl_question ON (  `questionid` = mdl_question.id ) 
GROUP BY questionid
```

Good luck!

Comment: After so long this is still a great answer! Is there way to add the quiz names that each question is linked to?

Answer (score -1):

The database tables used for quizes are covered at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Quiz_database_structure and https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overview_of_the_Moodle_question_engine#Detailed_data_about_an_attempt

This is not for the faint-hearted, as the sample query given on the 2nd link is:

```
SELECT
    quiza.userid,
    quiza.quiz,
    quiza.id AS quizattemptid,
    quiza.attempt,
    quiza.sumgrades,
    qu.preferredbehaviour,
    qa.slot,
    qa.behaviour,
    qa.questionid,
    qa.maxmark,
    qa.minfraction,
    qa.flagged,
    qas.sequencenumber,
    qas.state,
    qas.fraction,
    timestamptz 'epoch' + qas.timecreated * INTERVAL '1 second',  // OR FROM_UNIXTIME(qas.timecreated) IF you are ON MySQL.
    qas.userid,
    qasd.name,
    qasd.VALUE,
    qa.questionsummary,
    qa.rightanswer,
    qa.responsesummary

FROM mdl_quiz_attempts quiza
JOIN mdl_question_usages qu ON qu.id = quiza.uniqueid
JOIN mdl_question_attempts qa ON qa.questionusageid = qu.id
JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps qas ON qas.questionattemptid = qa.id
LEFT JOIN mdl_question_attempt_step_data qasd ON qasd.attemptstepid = qas.id

WHERE quiza.id = 675767

ORDER BY quiza.userid, quiza.attempt, qa.slot, qas.sequencenumber, qasd.name
```